# Python: Summing product of tuples inside a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with keyed tuples. I would like to multiply the 2 tuples and sum for every dictionary key.

I've created two classes. The first (`ExampleBase`) simply creates a variable and a dictionary. The second (`Useful`) passes the dictionary and does the calculation.

I believe I am calling the method from the second class (`Useful`) incorrectly as the error I'm currently getting is: 'ExampleBase' objest has no attribute 'compute_value'

The code should do this:

```
dictionary = {
    "key1": (v1, v2),
    "key2": (v1, v2),
    "key3": (v1, v2)
}

total = key1v1*key1v2 + key2v1*key2v2 + key3v1*key3v2
```

---

```
class ExampleBase:
    def __init__(self, company_name="N/A", stock_dict={}):
        """
        class constructor
        """
        self.company_name = company_name
        self.stock_dict = stock_dict
        print(self.stock_dict)       
        return


class Useful(ExampleBase):
    """
    Inherits from ExampleBase class
    """
    def __init__(self, company_name, stock_dict):
        super().__init__(name)
        return


    def compute_value(self, stock_dict):
        """
        Computes value of stk
        """
        sum(v1*v2 for v1,v2 in stock_dict.values())   
        return

##
## Program starts running from here
##
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = {"10-01-2014":(10, 11.25), "10-02-2014":(11, 12.25), "10-03-2014":(12, 13.25)}
    b = ExampleBase("Bern", a)
    b.compute_value(a)
```

Comment: A concrete example would make it easier to understand for us!

Comment: `key1v1*key1v2 + key2v1*key2v2 + key3v1*key3v2`, what does it mean?

Comment: So for my example (dictionary a) it would be: sum = 10*11.25 + 11*12.25 + 12*13.25)

Comment: I've also simplified the code since you're initial response. Right now I believe the error to be a syntax error regarding calling the method from class Useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `compute_value` function almost there. I complete your code. Regarding the error, that's because you call the function from `ExampleBase`.

```
class ExampleBase:
    def __init__(self, company_name="N/A", stock_dict={}):
        """
        class constructor
        """
        self.company_name = company_name
        self.stock_dict = stock_dict
        print(self.stock_dict)       
        return


class Useful(ExampleBase):
    """
    Inherits from ExampleBase class
    """
        def __init__(self, company_name, stock_dict):
            super().__init__(company_name)
            return


        def compute_value(self, stock_dict):
            """
            Computes value of stk
            """
            val = sum(v1*v2 for v1,v2 in stock_dict.values())   
            return val

    ##
    ## Program starts running from here
    ##
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        a = {"10-01-2014":(10, 11.25), "10-02-2014":(11, 12.25), "10-03-2014":(12, 13.25)}
        b = Useful("Bern", a)
        value = b.compute_value(a)
        print(value)
```

Also, if your intention for `compute_value` is to compute `stock_dict` that given when you create `Useful` instance,
    your class better goes like this:

```
class Useful(ExampleBase):
    """
    Inherits from ExampleBase class
    """
    def __init__(self, company_name, stock_dict):
        super().__init__(company_name, stock_dict)
        return


    def compute_value(self):
        """
        Computes value of stk
        """
        val = sum(v1*v2 for v1,v2 in self.stock_dict.values())   
        return val
```

with your `main`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = {"10-01-2014":(10, 11.25), "10-02-2014":(11, 12.25), "10-03-2014":(12, 13.25)}
    b = Useful("Bern", a)
    value = b.compute_value()
    print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

If you know each key is going to have a tuple value of length 2:

```
d = {'a': (1, 2), 'b': (3, 4)}
total = sum(a * b for a, b in d.values())
# total => 10
```

Otherwise:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce 
d = {'a': (1, 2), 'b': (3, 4, 5)}
total = sum(reduce(operator.mul, a, 1) for a in d.values())
# total => 62
```

Comment: I think he wants to multiply the values of `x`.